# Is it possible to mock builtins.hasattr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

Is it possible to mock `builtins.hasattr`? I try following way:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import unittest


class TestHasattr(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.hasattr')
    def test_hasattr(self):
        self.assertTrue(True, mock_name)
```

but I get recursion error:

```
test_hasattr (test_parser.TestHasattr) ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dkult\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1321, in decoration_helper
    yield (args, keywargs)
  File "C:\Users\dkult\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1348, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
TypeError: test_hasattr() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Your test is not written properly. The `mock.patch` introduces a new argument to the test class that you need to accept

Comment: What call to `hasattr` do you need to patch?